# how to change cropped image background color in ngx-awesome-uploader

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, image-upload, multifile-uploader

How can i change cropped image background color?

i tried send "fillColor" parameter with cropperOptions, but didn't work.

`this.cropperOptions = {
    dragMode: 'crop',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    autoCrop: true,
    movable: true,
    zoomable: true,
    scalable: true,
    autoCropArea: 1,
    minContainerWidth: 1200,
    minContainerHeight: 800,
    minCropBoxWidth: 1200,
    minCropBoxHeight: 800,
    fillColor: '#fff'
    };`

this parameters are running except fillColor parameter.

Default uploaded image:
[image]

top and bottom is black.

i wanna change this color with white.

I used this package:

npm: [ngx-awesome-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-awesome-uploader)

github: [ngx-awesome-uploader](https://github.com/vugar005/ngx-awesome-uploader)